# Where do methods go in a fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, methods

I've just started learning about Fragments in Android.

I was wondering where all my own code would go (i.e do I put my methods in the Fragment, or in the activity).

For example, I want to set text to multiple Textviews like so:

```
firstTextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myFirstText);
secondTextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mysecondText);
```

Where 'firstTextview' and 'secondTextview' are global variables, and my views are in a fragment xml (like 'fragment_main.xml').
Do I put this code in 'onCreate' in the activity, or 'onCreateView' in the fragment? And also, where would I define my global variables?

Is there anything else I would need to know about creating methods or using code in fragments?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will add code in your `onCreateView` of your class extending `Fragment`

Here is an example:

```
View main_view;

@Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    main_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment, container,false);
    firstTextview = (TextView) main_view.findViewById(R.id.myFirstText);

    secondTextview = (TextView) main_view.findViewById(R.id.mysecondText);
```

You must declare the Global Variables in the `Fragment` class.

Comment: Thanks. Just another question... If I am receiving data from an intent in a previous activity, would I declare the global variables for the intents in the fragment too? Just to clarify - thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If your `TextViews` are coming from `fragment.xml` then probably you could add your

textviews in `Fragment` in `onCreateView(...)` like

```
TextView firstTextview ,secondTextview; //defined Globally

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourLayout, container, false);

      firstTextview = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.myFirstText);
      secondTextview = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mysecondText);
}
```

Comment: Would I declare the global textviews in the fragment as well?

Comment: @FarbodSalamat-Zadeh yup as if you want to used it else where in `Fragement`